# Searchbox in Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

I have a simple problem with my code. the thing is my search box is working I can search my data into another sheet but the problem is I need to type the same text on the field. like if the data is written in caps-lock I need to type it with caps-lock too. I don't like that. I want to disable the case sensitive but how? can you help me please here's my screenshot of my code.

[image: screenshot]

here's my code

```
Sub searchData()
Dim erow As Long 
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim lastrow As Long
Dim count As Integer
Dim mySearch As Variant
Dim SearchString As String

    mySearch = Sheets("Control").Range("B2").Value 'Cell Input
    lastrow = Sheets("Data").Cells(Rows.count, 3).End(xlUp).Row

    For x = 2 To lastrow

    If Sheets("Data").Cells(x, 3) = mySearch Then
    'Loan Details
        Sheets("Control").Range("B4") = Sheets("Data").Cells(x, 1)
        Sheets("Control").Range("B5") = Sheets("Data").Cells(x, 2)
        Sheets("Control").Range("B6") = Sheets("Data").Cells(x, 3)
        Sheets("Control").Range("B7") = Sheets("Data").Cells(x, 4)
        Sheets("Control").Range("B8") = Sheets("Data").Cells(x, 5)
        Sheets("Control").Range("B9") = Sheets("Data").Cells(x, 6)
        Sheets("Control").Range("B10") = Sheets("Data").Cells(x, 7)
        Sheets("Control").Range("B11") = Sheets("Data").Cells(x, 8)
        Sheets("Control").Range("B12") = Sheets("Data").Cells(x, 9)
        Sheets("Control").Range("B13") = Sheets("Data").Cells(x, 10)
        Sheets("Control").Range("B14") = Sheets("Data").Cells(x, 11)
    'Personal Details
        Sheets("Control").Range("B15") = Sheets("Data").Cells(x, 12)
        Sheets("Control").Range("B16") = Sheets("Data").Cells(x, 13)
        Sheets("Control").Range("B17") = Sheets("Data").Cells(x, 14)
        Sheets("Control").Range("B18") = Sheets("Data").Cells(x, 15)
        Sheets("Control").Range("B19") = Sheets("Data").Cells(x, 16)
        Sheets("Control").Range("B20") = Sheets("Data").Cells(x, 17)
        Sheets("Control").Range("B21") = Sheets("Data").Cells(x, 18)
        Sheets("Control").Range("B22") = Sheets("Data").Cells(x, 19)
        Sheets("Control").Range("B23") = Sheets("Data").Cells(x, 20)
        Sheets("Control").Range("B24") = Sheets("Data").Cells(x, 21)
        Sheets("Control").Range("B25") = Sheets("Data").Cells(x, 22)
        Sheets("Control").Range("B26") = Sheets("Data").Cells(x, 23)
        Sheets("Control").Range("B27") = Sheets("Data").Cells(x, 24)
        Sheets("Control").Range("B28") = Sheets("Data").Cells(x, 25)
        Sheets("Control").Range("B29") = Sheets("Data").Cells(x, 26)
        Sheets("Control").Range("B30") = Sheets("Data").Cells(x, 27)
    'Employment Details
        Sheets("Control").Range("B31") = Sheets("Data").Cells(x, 28)
        Sheets("Control").Range("B32") = Sheets("Data").Cells(x, 29)
        Sheets("Control").Range("B33") = Sheets("Data").Cells(x, 30)
        Sheets("Control").Range("B34") = Sheets("Data").Cells(x, 31)
        Sheets("Control").Range("B35") = Sheets("Data").Cells(x, 32)
        Sheets("Control").Range("B36") = Sheets("Data").Cells(x, 33)


    End If

Next x

End Sub
```

Comment: Please post your code, it is very difficult to debug code in a screenshot.

Comment: did you think about using `Advanced Filter`? you can use your criteria with `*` if you don't want case sensitive or a full match, just part of it

Comment: i dont know how. all I can do is that. can you help me how and what should I need to add to my code? yes I want to turn off the case sensitive

Comment: UCase(Sheets("Data").Cells(x,3)) = UCase(mySearch)

Change the if condition to the code given,

Comment: YES I DID AND IT WORKED :) THANK YOU SO MUCH @nishitdey :) I'm working this for 1week omygod :)

Comment: I would also recommend copying a row or row range instead of each cell. It might be more efficient .. depending on the size of your data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the If condition to the below, this will automatically search the uppercase text, irrespective to what you have entered

```
UCase(Sheets("Data").Cells(x,3)) = UCase(mySearch)
```

For example:
in Sheet you have = "Sample" and in search box you have entered "sample
Searching will search like "SAMPLE = SAMPLE"

Comment: OH MY GOD! THANK YOU SO MUCH IT WORKED! :)

Comment: can you except this as answer. So that this question is resolved. Thanks